# Making an async request inside game loop (Python/Pygame)

Tags: python, asynchronous, pygame

I have never dealt with async requests yet and my issue is I have a **synchronous request inside an infinite loop** and it sometimes takes a while, **causing** the game running in the loop to **halt**

Simplified code would look like this:

```
while True:
    data = requests.get('some-url')

    # the game code that is sometimes being halted here
```

Is there a simple way of just adding an **await** or **async** keyword to the request and be done with it? **I don't mind data being old**, I'd rather prioritize the game loop running smoothly

Any nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciatted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I have never tried adding threading to pygame code, I can see no reason why it would not work.

Look at the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

You could start the long running thing in a thread and have it trigger a threading Event on completion (not a pygame event). You could have the threading Event create and trigger a pygame USEREVENT that you could pick up and respond to in your event loop.

Comment: Even though this seems like the way to go, I was kind of intimidated by it and ended up using ZeroMQ, a library that manages connections for you. Will upload a simplified version for any future people interested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Client

```
import requests

context = zmq.Context()

print('Client running...')
while True:
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
    socket.send_string(str(requests.get('the url to get info from').json()))
```

Server

```
import zmq
from my_game import game_step

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
data_received = False

while True:  # game loop
    try:
        data = socket.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK)
        data_received = True
    except Exception:
        data_received = False

    if(data_received):
        # do something with your data
        socket.send_string('generic response')  # need to send smth to keep connection flow

    game_step()  # advance game
```

This is as simple as I could write it

Note: make sure the port is the same!

Note 2: my_game would is the game library where pygame is included and run